# Android- How to get image size

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I have an image loaded asynchronously by its url. Then i set the layout width and height according to the size of the of the image loaded. Is there a way i can get this aside from getting the size from my ImageLoader class using BitmapFactoryOptions (i forgot the, if it is BitmapOptions or BitmapFactoryOptions). 
The problem is that at the start of the activity, the image is not rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quitely sure your case, but it is still able to get image's size by setting `BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true` even when the image is not rendered.

Comment: so, if the size is retrieved from my ImageLoader class, how can i pass it to my activity which holds the layout. or should i just set the imageview width and height in that ImageLoader class?